# Add ignored table to replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I had tables that were not replicated using replicate-ignore-table. The request is to start replicating them.

1. stopped the slave and stopped mysql.
2. commented out the relevant rows in /etc/my.cnf.
3. started mysql and started the slave.

But the tables were not created in the slave. How do I make them replicate?

We have Percona 5.6

Comment: You should resync the slave. Replication relies on binary logs that store every table modification. Even if you have the binlogs when the tables were created, you will need to reprocess them ignoring the remaining tables. It's not very practical, and very error-prone.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped to manage without it, but seems that you are right